# What's a hard dependency and what's a soft dependency?

Tags: magento2, module, dependency

In Magento 2 (any stable version) you can run this command `bin/magento info:dependencies:show-modules` and you will get a csv file in the root of your application called `modules-dependencies.csv` with all the module dependencies that looks like this:

[image]

**What is a Hard dependency and what is a Soft dependency?** An example of each would help.

Comment: check it may help http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/architecture/archi_perspectives/components/modules/mod_depend_types.html

Comment: @KetanKpBorada. Thanks. Good reading material, but an example of both hard and soft dependencies would help, If you have such an example, please put it as an answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are three different dependency parsers (implementations of `Magento\Setup\Module\Dependency\ParserInterface`):

- **code:** looks for classes used in code
- **config/xml:** looks for dependencies in module declaration
- **composer/json:** looks for dependencies in composer.json

The only one that makes a distinction between hard and soft dependencies is the composer parser (see: [Magento\Setup\Module\Dependency\Parser\Composer\Json::extractDependencies()](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/1ade3b769a937f19682bbbe4e51b6c956147952f/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Dependency/Parser/Composer/Json.php#L70-L93))

A **soft** dependency is a package, listed in "suggest", a **hard** dependency a package in "require".

The default dependency type is **hard**, that means dependencies found by the other parsers are always hard (see [Magento\Setup\Module\Dependency\Report\Dependency\Data\Dependency::__construct()](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/1ade3b769a937f19682bbbe4e51b6c956147952f/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Dependency/Report/Dependency/Data/Dependency.php#L46)).

Answer (score 13):

A simple and clear explanation (from the Magento U fundamentals course):

### Hard dependency

Implies that a **module *cannot* function without the other modules on which it depends.**

Example of hard dependencies include:

- The module **contains code that directly uses logic from another module** (instances, class constants, static methods, public class properties, interfaces and traits).
- The module **contains strings that include class names, methods names, class constants, class properties, interfaces, and traits from another module.**
- The module **de-serializes an object declared in another module.**
- The module **uses or modifies the database tables used by another module.**

`Magento_AdminNotification` has a hard dependency on `Magento_Store`

### Soft dependency

Implies that a **module *can* function without the other modules on which it depends.**

Example of soft dependencies include:

- The module **directly checks another module's availability.**
- The module **extends another module's configuration.**
- The module **extends another module's layout.**

`Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport` has a soft dependency on `Magento_CatalogImportExport` with code like this:

```
if (!$model instanceof \Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Export\Product\Type\AbstractType) {
    throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
        __(
            'Entity type model must be an instance of'
            . ' \Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Export\Product\Type\AbstractType'
        )
    );
}
```

If a module uses code from another module, it should declare the dependency explicitly.

EDIT: just noticed that this is also clearly explained in the official doc: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/architecture/archi_perspectives/components/modules/mod_depend.html